# How to set precision automatically in java

Tags: java, time, precision

I am trying to calculate performance for programs I wrote but the situation I came across is this...

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
my program....
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
end = end-start;

/* Below are things I tried which doesn't work
*********prints (same number of 0 as specified in decimalformat********
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.0000");
System.out.print("Execution time is " + formatter.format((end - start) / 1000d) + " seconds");
*********prints number but not able to put it in decimals ********
float time = end-start;
System.out.printf("%3.8f",time);
*/
```

How am I able to make it so it prints 0.000x time without print 0. 
For example if the program finishes in 0.7 milli seconds it should display 0.0007 seconds

Comment: You mean the first 0 ? please add an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

edit : I forgot the original purpose : performance measurement
Your actual code is fine, if it's just for simple measurement.
You should try looking for externals tools like jvisualvm (included in jdk) or [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/) if you want something more fancy and advanced

You should try formatting the final result using SimpleDateFormat.

```
 /**
 * Return date in specified format.
 * @param milliSeconds Date in milliseconds
 * @param dateFormat Date format 
 * @return String representing date in specified format
 */
public static String convertMilliSecondsToDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
{
    // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

    // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date. 
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);

     return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

More examples can be found [here](http://techwiki.ordak.org/index.php?title=How_To_Convert_Date_And_Time_In_Java).

It's a rather simple solution but you can try improving it by parsing the date and seeing the precision and displaying only the non-null part.

Comment: Can you copy the relevant examples from the link?  That's helpful if links go stale in the future.

Comment: In this case I am not converted into date but time. If i called 'public static long convertMilliSecondsToSeconds(long milliSeconds){
  return (milliSeconds / 1000);
 }'
which will not work since it is the same if i just use long as print. If I use the method you described above what am I going to input as dateFormat?